# List all drivers for all devices which are shown in device manager

Tags: windows, driver, wmic, device-manager

I am trying export using command line a list of all devices installed in the device manager, **including the hidden devices drivers** (which were once connected to the PC and not necessarily connected now). (device manager > view > show hidden devices).
In the list I want to have the **installed device driver version**

I tried the following but it doesn't give me a full list including hidden nor the device driver version:

```
driverquery /fo csv /v
WMIC Path Win32_PnPSignedDriver Get
WMIC Path Win32_systemDriver Get
WMIC Path Win32_PnPEntity Get
```

I would appreciate you help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command from CMD, after opening it as Administrator

```
SC QUERY TYPE=DRIVER
```